# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" и почему

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая, и какое правило работает:  — Ага! — крикнула в ответ, и с головой окунулась в воду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужна.

Работает правило использования запятой с «и» при однородных членах предложения. Однородными в данном случае являются глаголы-сказуемые.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае запятая не ставится, но существуют еще два варианта оформления подобных предложений (в обоих случаях перед союзом И делается пауза):

**1) Присоединительный союз И:**

— Ага! — крикнула в ответ, и с головой окунулась в воду.

Если союз и имеет присоединительное значение, то перед ним ставится запятая: "...она вслух читала романы, и виновата была во всех ошибках автора"

**2) Резкий переход:**

— Ага! — крикнула в ответ — и с головой окунулась в воду.

При указании на внезапность, неожиданность наступления действия  перед союзом и, соединяющим два однородных сказуемых, ставится тире: Скакун мой призадумался — и прыгнул.

[Розенталь. § 12. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100)

Comment: Только надо бы подчеркнуть, что эти запятая и тире – чисто авторские, а не запутывать, не наводить тень на ясный день (а "день" здесь яснее некуда – однородные сказуемые). "Присоединение" и "внезапность" здесь высосаны из пальца.

Comment: Вы весь текст прочитайте  и тогда давайте оценку знакам.  Здесь, с моей точки зрения,  пауза чувствуется, он просто художественно украсит предложение, а ее отсутствие воспринимается  как одномерное нанизывание слов. И потом, что у Вас с пальцем? Мне кажется, вы не зря  его постоянно вспоминаете. Мой совет:  говорите проще или хотя бы не повторяйтесь,  если хотите нас удивить или эмоционально воздействовать на аудиторию.

Comment: *запятая и тире – чисто авторские* Они авторские в каком-то смысле, но никак не "чисто", не волюнтаристские. Во-первых, тут нет явного подлежащего, это оставляет право на "авторскую" трактовку грамматики. Во-вторых, тире как знак периода никто не отменял. Да, это знак интонационный, но вполне известный грамматике/пунктуации.

Comment: По гамбургскому счету мне в ответе не нравится только одно. Понятие "присоединительного союза" в достаточной степени условно (лопатинская формулировка - это вообще до некоторой степени его авторская новация), не так просто отличить присоединительный союз от соединительного. Вот этот момент надо бы прояснить, почему вдруг а данном предложении возможна трактовка союза как присоединительного, "влет" я это не чувствую, тут видятся две **равноценные** составляющие.

Comment: — Ага! — крикнула в ответ, и при этом с головой окунулась в воду. Соединительный союз И обозначает последовательность действий, а здесь эта последовательность может быть непринципиальной, поэтому и равноценности нет. А  вот дополнительный  характер это сообщение может иметь.

Comment: Последовательность может быть непринципиальной?! Захлебнется же героиня! ))

Comment: *Соединительный союз И* - да вы не мне объясняйте, я вашу мысль понял. То была моя рекомендация по улучшению ответа.)) Ладно, не буду встревать, а то ваша с N. дискуссия уже и без меня основательно подогрета.

Comment: _Morkovkin: По гамбургскому счету мне в ответе не нравится только одно. Понятие "присоединительного союза" в достаточной степени условно (**лопатинская формулировка - это вообще до некоторой степени его авторская новация**)…_ === А при чём здесь Лопатин? По-моему, в ответе Sibylla процитирован  **не Лопатин, а Розенталь**.

Answer (score 2):

Авторская пунктуация, конечно, вещь неплохая, но! - непредсказуемая и необъяснимая.
**Тут-то как раз всё объяснимо, просто безграмотно.** Привожу примеры:

*Хорошо, что, спиночесалка, в виде Кира, всегда под рукой.*
*Мигом спустилась вниз, и нашла Кира и Алекса в столовой.*
*Алекс закатил глаза, и наигранно от нас отвернулся.*
*Возле пруда расстелили одеяло, и, сытые и довольные, молча лежали.*
*А он же и в правду почти чёрт.*
[**Н.Соболевская, Темная страсть**](https://lit-era.com/reader/temnaya-strast-b23897?c=239598)

Автор настойчиво ставит перед "и" запятую - надо и не надо.
И других ошибок в тексте - более чем предостаточно!

По "безавторским" правилам в выбранном Вами предложении запятая не нужна.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я так и не понимаю: где? почему? **о чём** кто-то спорит?
**НЕТ в безграмотности** причин для споров:

*...обряд я провел, поточу, что выбора у меня не было...

Я не видела, Алессио уже давно, и честно признаться ужасно по нему соскучилась.

Зато, Кир не переживает и без проблем оставляет нас наедине.*
*Последние несколько дней, мы практически не покидали пределы спальни.*

Comment: Да, список любопытный. Хотя и не все такие уж очевидные ошибки, набор впечатляет. Но послушайте, если брать исходную фразу без такого мощного контекста, то для неё Лопатин оставляет некоторую лазейку "грамматической" ("неавторской") запятой; он допускает трактовку "И" как присоединительного союза. Sibylla тут права. Другое дело, что такая семантика (*присоединение" уточняющей части) очень уж сомнительно. Но с этим надо разбираться без напрямую, без отсылок к другим случая авторской "оригинальности".

Comment: Спустилась и и нашла, закатил глаза и отвернулся, расстелили и лежали  - в этих примерах нет ПАУЗЫ. В грамматике  говорится:  чем больше степень СПАЯННОСТИ сказуемых,  тем ближе они к однородному ряду, а не к сложному предложению.    А спаянность - это одинаковая морфология, контактное расположение, близкая семантика. И когда всё это имеет место, то с паузой предложение просто не читается и запятой там неоткуда взяться. А в заданном  предложении (предположительно) есть то, что называют коммуникативной рассеченностью,  то есть отсутствует эта самая спаянность.  Текст надо брать и читать.